# Only uname/pwd verification over https - everything else in http

Tags: http, web-applications, https, security

For username/pwd verification - the good websites use https - to avoid sending cleartext password over the wire. If I have a site where I want to do this - i.e. login over https. However - after logging in the rest of the stuff should be over http. Is this possible - if yes, why don't we see too many websites doing this. If not, why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if yes, why don't we see too many websites doing this

The usual excuse for not using end-to-end TLS/SSL is that it causes the web app to take a performance hit, slow response times etc. This is a very flawed argument for https-sometimes security policy. Not entirely unfounded, but still unjustifiable.

> If not, why not?

The thinking is that the only inherently vulnerable aspect of user access control is the authentication phase, i.e. where you supply your username and password to prove you are who you say you are. Organizations are aware of the risk of transmitting the credentials in clear text. After this process however, authorization is carried out server side and the web app *trusts* you from there on out and there are no credentials to protect any more.

Or are there?
 As jszakmeister pointed out very succinctly, the session cookie is every bit as security critical as a username/password pair. Should someone get a hold of that, they might as well have seen the password and username on post-it.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to read up on [Firesheep](http://codebutler.com/firesheep).  The short form is that this technique allows malicious people to hijack the session.