# using https only at one page

Tags: http, https, security

I am trying to design an online judge website, which needs visitors to login.

I want to make sure the website is safe.I decided to use https but it seems that https is much slower than http. So I want to use https only at the login page.

I am a n00b about web dev. I googled it and tested it and I found that on a http page I can't get the data stored in the HTML5 localStorage by a https page. It's also impossible to post to a https page from a http page.
So what should I do? Put all the website in https or just using http(is there any secure way to protect the transferred data?)

PS:I want to send username and password through a https connection and get a key and an encrypted sessionID, and when the visitor post the next request, the ID will be decrypted and send to the server and the server will return another encrypted sessionID encrypted by the same key. So I just need to ensure the first connection is safe. Maybe there is a much better way?

Comment: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12540769/1530938)

Answer (score 0):

Just use HTTPS on your full site.  You'll save yourself a bunch of headaches.  The only significant performance hit is the initial part of a connection, and to the user, that'll be insignificant as well.  Regarding server performance, the browser will re-use established connections for quick subsequent requests reducing the load.  I question your assertion of "https is much slower"... is that an assumption or measured?

Comment: I googled the performance difference...I am sorry that I ignored the "keep-alive" options. Maybe you are right.